# Extension 'find' for browser, search in html, calculate and display larger, smaller or equal values

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'd like make a extension that find and highlight a values smaller, equal or greater in a html page. I am trying with JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Find a value smaller, equal or greater</h2>

<p>Your score:</p>

<input id="score" value="500" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var score, voteable;
    score = Number(document.getElementById("score").value);
    if (isNaN(score)) {
        voteable = "Input is not a number";
    } else {
        voteable = (score < 18) ? "lost :(" : "Won :)";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = voteable;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code "works fine", but I need change the **input** and **get** something like as the find (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) on browser that Calculate and show the results.

I'm having a little bit of difficulty.

Comment: don't know what  you want,,,

Comment: I'd like make a extension that I put a value (number) and highlight the numbers greater equal or smaller into a html page. Working likes as tool Find (cmd+F and ctrl+F).

PS: correction work fine to "work fine"

Thank you.

Comment: show picture what you want? hard to imagine